# When to run some code in a separate process

Tags: process, multiprocessing

I am trying to list the times in which it is useful to run some code in a separate process.
Does the following short list cover it?

1. **Speed**: the obvious one.

   - Multiprocess/distributed parallism
   - Worker process, vs GUI process for responsiveness of UI etc
2. **Security**:

   - No shared-memory space decreases attack vectors
   - Part of (but not all of) sandboxing
3. **Ability to interrupt on time out**:  This is a bit of a hack

   - Rather than filling all code with checks to see if have hit a time out condition, run it in its own process, and have a watch dog timer in the main process, which will trigger and interrupt vis SIGINT or failing that SIGKILL on the process doing the work after a timeout.
4. **Unreliable libraries**

   - Sometimes you find youself needing to use a library this is not reliable.
   - You can wrap that library into its own (actor) process
   - For example:

     - it might leak memory internally: solvable by restarting the process c
     - It might on certain corner-cases just segfault. Running it in its own process lets it crash without bringing down the whole process. So you can fail gracefully or restart the wrapper process.
   - Obviously one wish to avoid that by replacing the library. But one can't always do that immediately. And sometimes as a bussiness decision it might not be worth it.
5. **External Tools**

   - some tools are entire programs that are run on the commandline via. Obviously they run in their own process

Does that cover all the cases?

Comment: What is the point of making such a list? Note that ["list of things" questions will typically get closed as "too broad"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: Using multiple process doesn't improve performance over multiple threads in a single process in most scenarios.

Comment: @DocBrown One tends to differenciate between Long Lists, and short lists. Short list have a fixed length. As compaired to long lists which tend to be more or less shopping questions.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that does not change that using multiple processes is used for speed. (It has pros and cons vs multiple threads)

Comment: Well, I guess by thinking a while about this question this list can become at least medium sized ;-) So I don't see how there can be a "right" answer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: that is what I thought before I tried to use multithreading in C#, with several threads sharing the same garbage collector infrastructure. On at least 3 occasions, I invested the programming effort and switched to multiple processes, and guess what, I got a huge performance boost. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Add to that list:

1. **Programming Language Incompatibilty**

   You need to use a third party library for a specific task that has only a C interface while rest of your program is in Java.
2. **Compiler Version Incompatibility**

   You need to use a third party library for a specific task that is available only with a VS2010 build while rest of your program is in VS2015.
3. **Independent Distribution**

   You might find value in distributing/selling the two programs independently.